# How to store data in foreign key of a user table

Tags: laravel

The question is pretty simple. I am storing user's form data into table. I am using Auth login system of laravel, when user fill the input fields and register all values received in array called `$data` in create function (as you know code written in laravel as default) but when I save it in table, all values save expect `department_id` that is a foreign key. There is also a candidate_id and it is also a foreign key of candidate_table and it also save, but department_id have some issue.

### Blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{--<input style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="test" type="number" class="form-control" name="id" required autofocus>--}}
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>
                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="department" type="number" class="form-control" name="department" required autofocus>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

### User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function candidate()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Candidate::class,'candidate_id');
    }

    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class,'department_id');
    }

    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password','image','candidate_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

### Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Department;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
//          'candidate_id' => $data['id'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
             'department_id' => $data['department'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, for department_id input you have commented out form input field.

```
{{--<input style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="test" type="number" class="form-control" name="id" required autofocus>--}}
```

Uncomment the code and it will work fine. 
And because of it, it will not store department_id

Comment: <input style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="department" type="number" class="form-control" name="department" required autofocus> this is the department field and this is not hide

Comment: actually i have added some changes in register controller of auth but after some time i changed it as default.. can it be a reason?

Comment: actually it is a another filed that is not the part of code now. the field in my comment with name variable department this is the main thing that was received me in controller with $data array but not store in table attribute 'department_id' and table'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing...

`protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password','image','candidate_id'
    ];`

to

`protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password','image','candidate_id','department_id'
    ];`

Comment: oh man u beauti..i have forgotten totally.. and often i did.. but thanks alot..God bless u.

Comment: Bless me by accepting the answer :), this has got me many times... glad I could help!